# react-native SectionList scrollTo

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and tried using SectionList. Everything's working fine, so far. However, I can't seem to use the **scrollToLocation** function as defined in facebook's documentation. Anyone tried using it or anything similar? Basically, I want to scroll to a specific, section and item.

```
return Promise.all([
  props.orderActions.set(orders, true),
  props.orderActions.set(orders, false),
]).then(() => {
  return this._ordersList.scrollToLocation({
    animated: false,
    sectionIndex: 0,
    itemIndex: historyItems.length - 1
  })
})
```

_ordersList is a reference to the SectionList component.

Thanks!

Comment: whenever you post a question please make sure you add the code, so that reader can give a germane answer.

Comment: @Codesingh thanks for the feedback. I already updated the question

Comment: react-native version?

Comment: @Codesingh 0.44.0

Comment: I read somewhere that scrollToLocation is not been added in 0.44 so please try it with 0.45 and let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: @Codesingh just upgraded react-native. still not working.

Comment: @Codesingh got it working! just had a minor mistake in calling the component. THANKS!

Comment: what was your mistake ?

Comment: I called a different component. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to 0.45 did it. Had performance issues but managed to fix it by using PureComponent